Is a pro-algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with Galois action the inverse limit of Galois-equivariant quotients?
Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a pro-algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with a continuous action of $G_K$ for a field $K$ (if $\mathcal{G}$ were an abelian unipotent group, this is precisely a $p$-adic Galois representation).
Can $\mathcal{G}$ be expressed $G_K$-equivariantly as the inverse limit of algebraic groups (finite-type affine group schemes over $\mathbb{Q}_p$) with $G_K$-action?
In other words, for all $g \in \mathcal{G}$, does there exist a Galois-equivariant normal subgroup $\mathcal{N} \unlhd \mathcal{G}$ for which $g \notin \mathcal{N}$?
I feel like this should follow from compactness of $G_K$, possibly with an argument similar to the one that every $p$-adic Galois representation has a $G_K$-equivariant lattice. But I haven't quite been able to figure it out. Roughly, one would consider an arbitrary normal subgroup $N$ of $\mathcal{G}$, then consider
$$
\bigcap_{g \in G_K} gN,
$$
and hope to use compactness of $G_K$ to show that the quotient by this subgroup is finite-type as a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-scheme.

Shouldn't there be some sort of additional hypotheses to assert that an abelian unipotent group with $G_K$-action is a Galois representation?  I would have thought that you'd need at least smoothness and connectedness—and separately that the action preserves the linear structure, though maybe there's some reason that's automatic?

Sorry, smoothness and connectedness of what? A unipotent group over a field of characteristic 0 is automatically smooth and connected. The category of abelian unipotent groups over a field of characteristic 0 is equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Re, right, sorry, I've been spending a lot of time in positive characteristic lately.

@LSpice, oooh, tsk! :)

What does 'continuous' action of $G_K$ mean for you? Perhaps you could bake the requisite property into the definition of continuity, but there are naturally occurring examples of actions of $G_K$ on pro-algebraic groups which are not limits of finite-dimensional Galois-equivariant quotients. For example, if $X$ is a variety over $K$ with a $K$-point $x$, there is an action of $G_K$ on the pro-algebraic completion over $\mathbb{Q}p$ of the etale fundamental group $\pi_1(X{\bar{K}},x)$, and typically it is not the inverse limit of finite type groups with a Galois action.

If it were, every continuous finite-dimensional representation of $\pi_1(X_{\bar{K}},x)$ would be embeddable into a finite-dimensional representation that extends to the arithmetic fundamental group $\pi_1(X, x)$, and this fails already for $X=\mathbb{A}^1_K\setminus 0$ if $K$ has finitely many roots of unity. In this example (if $\mathrm{char} K=0$) the connected component of the identity of this group scheme is a pro-torus and most of its characters have infinite orbit under the action of $G_K$, so they cannot factor through a finite-dimensional Galois-equivariant quotient.
